# How to cache all images without displaying them with fresco?

Tags: android, image

I want to cache all images without displaying them so that the image will be displayed even if there isn't any available network
Is it possible with [Fresco Image Loader](https://frescolib.org/)?

Comment: [disk cache](https://frescolib.org/docs/caching.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, see their [cache](https://frescolib.org/docs/caching.html) page for details.

To configure the cache you should do something like:

```
DiskCacheConfig diskCacheConfig = DiskCacheConfig.newBuilder()
   .set....
   .set....
   .build()

// when building ImagePipelineConfig
.setMainDiskCacheConfig(diskCacheConfig)
```

Then to check if it persisted in the local storage cache, you can use:

```
DataSource<Boolean> inDiskCacheSource = imagePipeline.isInDiskCache(uri);
DataSubscriber<Boolean> subscriber = new BaseDataSubscriber<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected void onNewResultImpl(DataSource<Boolean> dataSource) {
      if (!dataSource.isFinished()) {
        return;
      }
      boolean isInCache = dataSource.getResult();
      // your code here
    }
  };
inDiskCacheSource.subscribe(subscriber, executor);
```

To prefetch the images you can use something like:

```
final PrefetchSubscriber subscriber = new PrefetchSubscriber();
for (Uri uri : mUris) {
  final DataSource<Void> ds = Fresco.getImagePipeline().prefetchToDiskCache(ImageRequest.fromUri(uri), null);
  ds.subscribe(subscriber, UiThreadImmediateExecutorService.getInstance());
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/imagepipeline/ImagePipelinePrefetchFragment.java) their full sample for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answer I have read that on the fresco documentation but  I look for some simple imlementation like https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads @dan

Comment: @MetinIlhan Not sure I understand, if you are looking for something like glide, why not use glide directly? If you are looking to prefetch (download only) the images with fresco, you can take a look at their sample here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/imagepipeline/ImagePipelinePrefetchFragment.java

Comment: thank you very much, **  imageView.setController(
        Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setOldController(imageView.getController())
            .setUri(Uri.parse(url))
            .build()); **  when call ımage on ofline some images are not diplayed

Comment: You are welcome! For the other issue, please post another question with the sample code, this way we will be able to understand what is happening and you will get better suggestions.